# Error Java Problems The method action() of type ModelT1000 must override

Tags: java, spring

[image]

I'm a beginner in Java development and I don't know what to do about the errors displayed in this picture.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Providing the sample code would also be a good start.

Comment: Post **code** not pictures. I have no idea what that link takes me to; and I'm not stupid enough to follow it at work. This holds true for the majority of people here.

Answer (score 0):

The [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation means that the method must override a method from a parent class/interface.

Either remove these annotations, or have your class extend/implement one that has those methods.